# error importing numpy

Tags: numpy, python-2.6

I have strange error, when I try to import numpy:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timo/malltul/mafet/src/mafet/core/pattern.py", line 7, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 147, in <module>
    import ma
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/ma/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    import core
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 4850, in <module>
    all = _frommethod('all')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 4824, in __init__
    self.__doc__ = self.getdoc()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 4830, in getdoc
    signature = self.__name__ + get_object_signature(meth)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/numpy/ma/core.py", line 109, in get_object_signature
    import inspect
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/tokenize.py", line 38, in <module>
    COMMENT = N_TOKENS
NameError: name 'N_TOKENS' is not defined
```

It seems that the cause of the problem is that my script is in my own package named `core` and whenever I try to import `numpy` there, I get the error. Importing works fine elsewhere.

The only solution I've got this far is to rename my 'core' package to something else. Why does this matter? Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Python2.6 on Ubuntu 10.14 . Numpy version is 1.3.0 .

EDIT: Actually renaming my package does not fix it. Renaming token.py in my package fixes it. Sorry for the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt this has anything to do with your `core` module or with `numpy`.

From the stack trace, it would appear that the problem is with the `tokenize` module, which is part of Python, not part of `numpy`. `Tokenize` does `from token import *` and then uses `N_TOKENS` that's defined in `token.py`.

First of all, I'd check that there's no stray module called `token` on your `PYTHONPATH`:

```
>>> import token
>>> token.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.6/token.pyc'
```

If this picks up the above file yet you still get the problem, I'd suggest reinstalling Python.

Comment: It seems that my own module token.py caused the trouble.

Comment: @Timo: Yes, this sounds very plausible. As a permanent fix, I'd suggest calling your module something else.

Comment: Ah, this fixed my problem. I have added a file named `token.py` in my workspace and that path as added to `PYTHONPATH`.