# Cannot import flask

Tags: python, flask

In command line `python -c 'import flask'`

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
    __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 67, in <module>
    from werkzeug._internal import _get_environ
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/_internal.py", line 13, in <module>
    import inspect
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tokenize.py", line 39, in <module>
    COMMENT = N_TOKENS
NameError: name 'N_TOKENS' is not defined
```

How can I solve it?

Met this error in my flask project, although yesterday everything was fine.

Comment: Do you have a file called `token.py`? I suspect that it interferes with the standard library file that contains the `N_TOKENS` constant. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/token.py#L64

Comment: Looks the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067223/nameerror-name-n-tokens-is-not-defined ?